# Storing a MVC Model Property to a JavaScript var object syntax error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

for some reason I am getting a syntax error when trying to use Razor syntax to store a model object into a JavaScript var. After researching google it seems that I should be able to do something like this. I am using a script tag in my cshtml to do this (I know this is bad practice but I came in late in this project so I'm doing this for uniformity sake) so here is the code.

Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
    var isAvailable = @Model.IsAvailable; // This gives me a syntax error
</script>
```

I have a Model class with the Boolean property named IsAvailable and I'm trying to store it in the var isAvailable but Visual Studio doesn't like it. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: It literally says "Syntax Error", lol. The red error line is right after the semi-colon

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Is it showing an error when you run it ? Also, remember `True` is not `true`.

Comment: Is **IsAvailable** a boolean? Anyway, try to enclose it on quotes:   var isAvailable = **"@Model.IsAvailable"**

Comment: `True` is not `true`. So you should try something liek `var isAvailable = @(Model.IsAvailable? "true" : "false");`

Comment: so when I run it with the error says that either TRUE or FALSE is undefined?

Comment: @Jorge i'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Jorge that worked. Just returns the string "True" or "False". This is manageable though. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default MVC calls ToString(), which Booleans converted to string produce upper-cased values (ie. True) where JS boolean syntax requires lower-cased (ie. true).  Try this:

```
var isAvailable = @(Model.IsAvailable.ToString().ToLower());
```

Comment: If I put single quotes around what is inside the parentheses, then this works perfectly. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<script>
    var isAvailable = @(Model.IsAvailable) ; 
</script>
```

If not this will surely work:

```
<script>
    var isAvailable = ('@Model.IsAvailable.ToLower()'=='true'); 
</script>
```